# How to get a Clob using java

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, clob, db2-luw

I'm having some problem to get a Clob field using java. So this is what I've done:

```
    String 
    sql = ("SELECT DBMS_LOB.substr(LDTEXT, 1000) AS TEXT "
        +  "FROM LONGDESCRIPTION ");

    try (Connection connection = BDOracle.abreConexaoDB2();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            ) {

        while (resultSet.next()) {
```

It breaks here:

```
            Clob clob = (Clob) resultSet.getClob("TEXT");

            long length = clob.length();
            String out = clob.getSubString(1, (int) length);
        }           

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
```

Exception returns:

> ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
>   [jcc][t4][1092][11644][3.53.70] 
>   invalid data conversion wrong result column type for requested conversion.

The query works fine on the database, I'm using DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `LDTEXT` is a `CLOB`, `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` will return a `VARCHAR` value, as [indicated in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055128.html). Subsequently, you should use `getString()`, not `getClob()` to retrieve it (and use the correct column name -- you have `TEXT0` while the query defines it as `TEXT`).

Comment: You were right! I changed the code and used "getString()" and it worked perfectly. Many thanks